# UIView splits into 2 parts with animation

Tags: ios

I am working with UIView. I want to do animation on that view. While clicking on the view it should be divided into 2 parts and move towards both sides. Please help me with a proper solution.

Comment: Can you describe it little briefly what exactly you want to do?

Comment: UIView contains CALayers with images. While clicking on the view it should be departed into two and disappear with animation. Then the same view with some other images should appear with animation.

Comment: checkout this link :-https://github.com/Split82/HMGLTransitions

Answer (score 1):

```
@implementation SplitView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *ges = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(split)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:ges];
        [ges release];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)split {
    CGRect f = self.frame;
    CGRect f1 = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(f), f.origin.y, f.size.width/2, f.size.height);
    CGRect f2 = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(f), f.origin.y, f.size.width/2, f.size.height);

    SplitView *view1 = [[[SplitView alloc] initWithFrame:f1] autorelease];
    [self.superview addSubview:view1];

    SplitView *view2 = [[[SplitView alloc] initWithFrame:f2] autorelease];
    [self.superview addSubview:view2];

    f1.origin.x -= 30;
    f2.origin.x += 30;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    view1.frame = f1;
    view2.frame = f2;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

Try to create such UIView class.